# Loading stl files in three.js in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, three.js, stl-format

I'm running into an interesting problem where I'm trying to use three.js inside of a ruby on rails project. The problem occurs specifically when I try to load external stl files to be viewed. I've set it up where people upload designs and in the design there is an id, the name of the file, and the stl file. Then I want three.js to retrieve the url of the file and display it. Whenever I try to run it inside of my RoR project I get this error:

> Started GET "/designs/slotted_disk" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 20:11:30 -0700
>   Processing by DesignsController#show as */*
>
> Parameters: {"id"=>"slotted_disk"}
>
> User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '...' LIMIT 1
>
> Design Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "designs".* FROM "designs" WHERE "designs"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "slotted_disk"]]
>
> Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Design with id=slotted_disk):
>     app/controllers/designs_controller.rb:19:in `show'

From what I can gather I'm running into some sort of problem where ruby on rails thinks I'm trying to pass in a new design and setting the id to the name of the design file. I can't find anything online that covers this, any help would be very appreciated!

RoR controller code (designs_controller.rb)

```
    def show
        @design = Design.find(params[:id])
    end
```

RoR views code (show.html.erb)

```
    <% provide(:title, @design.name) %>
    <div class="row">
      <aside class="span4">
        <section>
          <h1>
            <%= @design.name %>
          </h1>
          <div id="viewer"></div>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "three.min"     %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "STLLoader"     %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "TypedGeometry" %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "Detector"      %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "stats.min"     %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "render_file"   %>
       </section>
      </aside>
   </div>
```

three.js code (render_file.js)

```
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

      var geometry = event.content;
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

      mesh.position.set( 0.136, - 0.37, - 0.6 );
      mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0.3, 0 );
      mesh.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );

      mesh.castShadow = true;
      mesh.receiveShadow = true;

      scene.add( mesh );
    } );
    loader.load( 'slotted_disk.stl' );
```